# Can Wall of Force have corners?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

From [Wall of Force](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-force/):

> The caster can form the wall into a flat, vertical plane whose area is up to one 10-foot square per level. The wall must be continuous and unbroken when formed. If its surface is broken by any object or creature, the spell fails.

Does this allow or disallow making a shape (such as a square or rectangle) relative to looking down? For example, could a (typical) large creature be surrounded by four 10x10ft squares of this spell in a single cast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, [Wall of Force](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-force/) creates a single wall

The spell effect and spell description speak on the singular, *a wall*.

> Effect wall whose area is up to one 10-ft. square/level
>
> A wall of force creates an invisible wall of pure force.
>
> The caster can form the wall into a flat, vertical plane whose area is up to one 10-foot square per level. The wall must be continuous and unbroken when formed.

If the wall could be split into sections, it would now be multiple walls. A common house room has at four walls, for instance.

There are two spell levels of difference between *Wall of Force* and [Forcecage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/forcecage/), which does exactly a small room made out of walls of force. It wouldn't make sense for *Forcecage* to exist if *Wall of Force* could be shaped and create an effect similar to *Forcecage*.

Look at one of the effects of *Forcecage*:

> Windowless Cell: This version of the spell produces a 10-foot cube with no way in and no way out. **Solid walls of force form its six sides**.

Answer (score 4):

I’d say no because it says flat and in a (singular) plane. Making corners creates multiple planes, violating the conditions of the spell.